# Moving a WordPress side bar

Tags: wordpress, widget, themes, edit

Hi Guys i am working on a WordPress theme, I have moved the Widget area from the base of the page to the top right. Which is not the problem the problem is that when I expand the Widget area it shifts all the page content down which is something I would like to avoid if possible.

any help would be great.

some extra information:

i am using the spun theme.
Edit: 08/07/2013

Aaron Lee: i have am using the Z-index as well but it still shifts the content down.

fixed it it involved me changing relative to absolute which allows for the bleed into the other divs. thank you Aaron lee your answer was right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the z-index of the widget area higher so that it layers over the top of the page and therefore shouldn't effect other elements when it is moved in terms of its position.

```
.classForWidget{
   z-index:999;
 }
```

Set that on there and it should help, this is assuming that you are altering the size/position of the widget on the live page, as in an adjustable div etc.